# How to configure footer on first page with Exam package?

Tags: exam, footer

With the following example, I cannot change the first page footer.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\firstpagefooter{left}{middle}{Page \thepage\ sur \numpages}
\title{Exam}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{questions}
\question Lorem Ipsum
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

It seems the `\firstpagefooter` or even the `\footer` command don't work.

What's wrong?

In my usecase, I redefine the `\maketitle` command:

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\firstpagefooter{left}{middle}{Page \thepage\ sur \numpages}
\title{Exam}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \begin{center}%
    {\LARGE \bfseries\@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vskip 1em
  \thispagestyle{foot}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{questions}
\question Lorem Ipsum
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or replace ALL of \maketitle.  Better yet, call it something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\maketitle` command forces `\pagestyle{plain}` for this first page.

If you want to change the style, add before `\begin{document}`

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}
{\thispagestyle{plain}}
{}{}{}
```

[image: a]

If you want to use the same footer on all subsequent pages, use

```
\footer{left}{middle}{Page \thepage\ sur \numpages}
```

instead of `\firstpagefooter`

To use a **custom first page** define a new command, like   `\maketitleALT`

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\footer{left}{middle}{Page \thepage\ sur \numpages}
\title{Exam}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\maketitleALT}{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\centering
{\LARGE \bfseries\@title \par}%
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vskip 1em
\thispagestyle{foot}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \maketitleALT % changed <<<<<<<<<<
    \begin{questions}
        \question Lorem Ipsum
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: b]

Comment: I've edited my question. In my case I redefined the `\maketitle`. How should I solve the issue?

Comment: @nowox  Please see the updated answer.